# trace.writeline not working in azure Onstop method

Tags: azure

I am wondering why the following azure workerrole does not show any diagnostic messages when the role is shutdown:

```
public class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint {

private bool running=true;

    public override void Run() {
        while (running)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            TTrace.WriteLine("working", "Information");
        }
        Trace.WriteLine("stopped", "Information");
    }

    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("starting", "Information");
        return base.OnStart();
    }

    public override void OnStop() {
        Trace.WriteLine("stopping", "Information");
        running = false;
        base.OnStop();
    }
}
```

I can see the events 'starting' and 'working' in the diagnostic logs, but the Onstop method does not log anything. I was wondering if it's even called so I injected some code in the OnStop() method to write out some data. In fact the data was written as expected which proves that the method is called, it's just that I don't get any logs. Any ideas how to Trace my shutdown code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first and best guess is that the Diagnostics Agent does not have time to transfer the trace out to storage for you to see it.  Traces are first logged locally on the VM, then the agent will transfer them off (OnDemand or Scheduled) depending on how you have configured it.  Once the VM shuts down, the agent is gone too and cannot transfer it off.

Comment: +1, that's why it's worth writing logs directly to persistent storage, otherwise you don't have the logs for periods when you need them the most.

Comment: @sharptooth - I don't generally recommend to write directly to storage for tracing purposes.  Without more engineering work, most folks will end up blocking their app with an IO bound call.  Timeouts, network conditions, etc. can cause issues there - and for something that is simple like tracing, that should never happen.

Answer (score 1):

Tracing in OnStop is not supported and if you manage to get it working via  On-Demand Transfer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433075.aspx ) it's likely to not work in the next release.  Note, tracing in Web Role OnStart does not work either. See my blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/12/21/optimal-azure-restarts.aspx to fix that. Also see my blog post for instructions on view real time OnStop trace data with DbgView.

The OnStop method should be used only to delay shutdown until you've cleaned up - so you shouldn't have much code in there to trace. Again, see my blog for details.